# Azure Function App - duplicate log entries?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

I have started getting duplicate log entires in the "Logs" view in "Monitoring" section in the "Function App" and "Application Insight" resources.

But when I check the "Log Analytics" resource I also have, which are targets for sending log data to from the two earlier resources, they only show up once.

I also checked with the kudu view and those logfiles, where there is only 1 entry in "C:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\xxxx> "
But i also found that the same stuff is written to the logfiles in
"C:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host> " as well.

Might this be the reason? If so, how would I prevent this duplicate logging?

My Host.json file for the function app lookes like this right now:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Critical",
      "Host.Results": "Error"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 20,
        "excludedTypes": "Exception"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to modify it to change not only loglevels, but the categories as well. But still no dice. It used to have a few more per the function app documentation that microsoft has ([this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2)), which at the start worked fine, but then suddenly entries started appearing twice.

Function App code snippet:

```
[FunctionName("Program")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        string request = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        log.LogInformation($"Webhook Recieved: {request}");
        // Environment Variables
        var xxxContext = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("xxx", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        var xxxToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("xxx", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        var yyyKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("yyy", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        var yyySecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("yyy", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

        // API Clients
        var xxxClient = new xxxNet(Convert.ToInt32(xxxContext), xxxToken);
        var yyyClient = new yyyClient(yyyKey, yyySecret, "....");

        // Main function
        var body = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Webhook>>(request);
        var response = "";
        foreach (var item in body)
        {
            if (item.Status != "Completed") continue;
            var uriSplit = item.ResourceUri.Split('/');
            var salesOrderNr = uriSplit[^1];
            var orderType = uriSplit[^2];
            try
            {
                var salesOrder = await xxxClient.SalesOrder.Get(salesOrderNr, orderType);
                var bodyparms = new
                {
                    status = "completed"
                };
                var success = await yyyClient.Order.Update(salesOrder.customerOrder, bodyparms);
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError(ex, "Exception when trying to process webhook");
                response = string.Format("exception when trying to process webhook: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(response) ? new OkObjectResult("Weborder has been updated") : new BadRequestObjectResult(response);
    }
```

Images:

[What it looks like in Logs in the Function App resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD3hS.png)

[What it looks like in Logs in the Log Analytics resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd4IY.png)

Comment: I had the similar issue not consistently but every now and then. Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortuately no.
For some reason, probably similar to yours, it suddenly stopped giving duplicate entries without any changes made. But we chose to just live with any duplicates as it doesn't really harm us.